# How to validate clone elements in jQuery validation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using [bassistance.de/jquery-plugins](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

and this is default jQuery form validation service.

I am aware that question related to jQuery validation asked too many times but my problem is
little bit different.

I have one form with one file input and i am cloning like below

```
var picFields = $('#file').clone(true);
```

and appending into the form to upload multiple file.

while cloning i have class with 'required' name and adding the rule like

```
$('.required').each(function() {
 $(this).rules('add', {
    required: true,
 });
});
```

and initially validating like

```
$('#form').validate();
```

its validating only the first element not all the dynamic added fields.

Comment: Your entire `.rules('add')` method is superfluous.  If the fields already have a `class` of `required`, then the field will automatically be `required` without having to do anything else.  However, if you fail to include a unique `name` attribute on every field, then you'll have the exact problem you've described.

Comment: jsFiddle  of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/nvK7F/. I'm looking for a solution...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every input needs an unique name.  The plugins fails to consider things like 
name="location[]", you have to add an index (correct would have been name="location[0]").
For cloned elements I get first the html "clone().html()" then I replace the [0] 
with a counter number i keep track  Ex: .replace(/[0]/g, "["+cont+"]")

then I can safely append the generated html to the DOM and the plugin works as usual.

REMEMBER: JQUERY VALIDATE NEEDS AN UNIQUE NAME IN THE INPUT!! I pay myself with a lot of hours lost for this.

Answer (score 0):

Solve it !

What I used to do: after I clone the object, I called a function that creates the validation:

```
function add_another_form(){
     var new_form =  jQuery(".class").clone(true);
     new_form.appendTo(".parent");
     add_validation_for_forms();//attach again the validation !
}

function add_validation_for_forms(){
    jQuery(".class").validate({....})
```

But that was not working, so I just used a *.each* function in there, and it works now...

```
function add_validation_for_forms(){
    jQuery(".class").each(function(){
        jQuery(this).validate({....})
```