# jQuery validate on cloned form fieldsets works but is ignored by .valid() method on the form element

Tags: clone

I'm sure this has come up many, many times before but I am at my wit's end with this problem. I'll try and be as descriptive as possible without bloating the problem statement.

I am using the jQuery validate plugin for form validation. All form rules and messages are retrieved via ajax and then initialised. All form validation works like a charm until I start cloning fieldsets inside the form to give the user the ability to add additional entries.

The input fields react exactly as they should to changing values (error highlights and displaying messages etc), but when I call the .valid() method on the form it ignores the additional fieldset cloned from the first.

I have added test rules after cloning the fieldset, and again, the input field responds correctly to the newly assigned rule but gets ignored when calling .valid() on the form element.

I will add code snippets should anyone be willing to help me find the problem.

Thanks in advance!
Fred

Edit:

I have found that the .valid() method only uses the first fieldset in the form. Take note that all input names of cloned fieldsets are the same as the original. For example, say i have a field called productName in my original fieldset and i clone it, I will now have two inputs in the form with the same name attribute.

Could it be that jQuery validate only cares about the first instance it reaches and validates on that? I have seen posts about jQuery validate not playing nice with duplicate input names on forms but i believe it was resolved.

Comment: Few things - first are the names of the fields unique?

Comment: Hey! Nope, they are not, as specified in my last edit =)

Comment: one sec, busy making a fiddle

Comment: Heres a fiddle to replicate the issue 
http://jsfiddle.net/nvK7F/ 

I have a feeling its either a bug in jQuery or the validation plugin

Comment: Spot on! The question now is how to address the problem? Should one submit an issue on the plugin's github? How have you dealt with issues like this in the past?

Comment: solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29633102/2615737